# github action workflow_run example of official document

Tags: github-actions

I"m a newbie of github action.

I looked into `workflow_run` [document](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run) and had a one question.

Below is the codes.

```yaml
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [Upload data]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  download:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: 'Download artifact'
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            let allArtifacts = await github.rest.actions.listWorkflowRunArtifacts({
               owner: context.repo.owner,
               repo: context.repo.repo,
               run_id: context.payload.workflow_run.id,
            });
            let matchArtifact = allArtifacts.data.artifacts.filter((artifact) => {
              return artifact.name == "pr_number"
            })[0];
            let download = await github.rest.actions.downloadArtifact({
               owner: context.repo.owner,
               repo: context.repo.repo,
               artifact_id: matchArtifact.id,
               archive_format: 'zip',
            });
            let fs = require('fs');
            fs.writeFileSync(`${process.env.GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/pr_number.zip`, Buffer.from(download.data));

      - name: 'Unzip artifact'
        run: unzip pr_number.zip
```

This workflow triggered by `Upload data` downloads an artifacts from triggering data.

But seems to me that it is too complex.

Why doesn't this workflow use `download-artifact` action?

I would implement above workflow like below.

```yaml
jobs:
  download:
    steps:
      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: pr_number
          path: $MY_WORKSPACE
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: Just an impression, but two thoughts: 1) I would guess the manual also tries to show how you would implement this, which has lasting value, and 2) the manual might have before that action was written. But at this point I would think it useful if the manual showed the shorter option too, I'm with you on that!